# Unable to sign in to Evernote account using Tusk - this browser or app may not be secure error

Tags: login, security, snap

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

I have installed Tusk app using snapcraft

`sudo snap install tusk`

Now when I open the app after signing in it shows the error message -

> This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
>
> Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

[image]

Comment: When I google I do not find an app call Tusk what is it?

Comment: @David Tusk is unofficial evernote client for Ubuntu

Comment: same problem here